# ImportError: No module named lxml when invoking from java Front end scripts

Tags: java, python-2.7, lxml

I have a script which does XML reconfig using lxml module.
It works fine flawlessly when i invoke it using python script using external functions.

```
from lxml import etree
def restructure_xml(self,xml):
    """
        Returns a restructured xml tree moving parameter nodes above child object nodes.
    """
    parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True) # lxml.etree only!
    tree = etree.parse(xml, parser)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root:
        childIterList=[]
        for node in child.iter():
            childIterList.append(node)

        childIterList.reverse()
        for node in childIterList:
        #if no. of children is 0, that is a parameter node
            if len(node) ==  0:
                node.getparent().insert(0, node)
    return tree
```

But it would throw an error when the same is invoked using Front end Java.

```
from lxml import etree
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

Python version - 2.7
lxml version - 3.2.3

java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: What is "Front end Java"?

Comment: We are invoking Python scripts from the front-end GUI which is programmed in Java. So i said we have, front-end-java.

Comment: "A front-end GUI which is programmed in Java". OK, but how can I reproduce the problem?